# How to keep ObjectId values instead of null in Mongoose populate() when no match is found?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm using the populate() method in Mongoose to fill a specific field. However, in some cases when there is no matching record in the other collection, the populate() method returns null. I would like to keep the original ObjectId values of the missing records instead of null. Because in the following phases of the code, I edit the documents and save them. Since those fields are null, they are being saved as null too. I want to keep their original ObjectId values, even though there is no corresponding collection. I want to populate "lockAccessAssignment" fields. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
const authorizationReflectionsWithGivenLockAccessAssignmentId = await AuthorizationReflection.find({
      'authorizationInfoWithMetaDataList.lockAccessAssignment': lockAccessAssignmentId,
    })
      .populate('user')
      .populate({
        path: 'authorizationInfoWithMetaDataList.lockAccessAssignment'
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'authorizationInfoWithMetaDataList.lockAccessAssignment',
        populate: {
          path: 'lockingComponentId',
          model: 'LockingComponent'
        },
      });
```